# wordpress language filter qtranslate

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I have a single page scrollable website with wordpress as CMS. The website is in three languages and I'm using the qtranslate plugin in wordpress.

I'm new to wordpress and my issue is i'm not sure how to link the posts to appropriate language pages. I have the english on working fine.

This is how I link the content in my english version:

```
<?php $test = new WP_Query('category_name=welcome&showposts=1');
while ($test->have_posts()) : $test->the_post(); ?>                                 
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Any help.. or alternate options is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: you can go to post details page using post id as well

Comment: Where have you put option of language switching ? When any of the language selected from language option, automatically content will change in to that language.
**Note**:For that you need to add content in every language.

Comment: i don't understand. could you please explain?

Comment: i have the language switching on the header. And the content does not change. <li><a href="url/de/">DE</a></li><li><a href="url/fr/">FR</a></li>

Comment: Suppose you are on some post, and on that page when you switch language, Where is it redirecting you ?

Comment: Have you added that language switcher from the widget ?

Comment: to the same page with some broken css

Comment: No its not from a widget.

Comment: Add from widget and then try again ,

Comment: for some reason. The widget option under appearance is not available.

Comment: Do you have any **sidebars** in your theme ? If no, then please register sidebar in terms to view widget.

Comment: <li><a hreflang="de" href="https://url/?lang=de">DE</a></li>
<li><a hreflang="fr" href="url/?lang=fr">FR</a></li> I changed my links to this and it works :)